# How to fix 'Encountered the symbol' when creating store procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, compiler-errors

I would like to create procedure to check if the records exists then updated else insert.However, there is an issue that I have tried to solve it but I cannot solve it.Please help.

```
CREATE TABLE JOB_RUN
(
DATE_KEY VARCHAR2(8),
JOB_NAME VARCHAR2(20),
START_DATE TIMESTAMP,
CTL_ROWS NUMBER,
LOAD_DATA_ROW NUMBER,
END_DATE TIMESTAMP,
FLAG_COMPLETED CHAR(1),
PRIMARY KEY (DATE_KEY,JOB_NAME)
);
```

Here is the sample value of the fields:

```
INSERT INTO JOB_RUN(DATE_KEY,JOB_NAME,START_DATE,CTL_ROWS,LOAD_DATA_ROW,END_DATE, FLAG_COMPLETED)
        VALUES('20110101','TABLE_NAME',SYSDATE,10,0, NULL, 'N');
```

Then, I have created the Procedure to receive date_key and job_name

```
create or replace procedure check_job(pdate IN varchar2,pname IN varchar2) as
declare
v_count int;
    begin
        select count(*) into v_count from MISDBA.job_run where (date_key=pdate and job_name=pname);
        if v_count = 1 then
            update job_run
            set start_date=sysdate,ctl_rows=5;
        else         
        insert into misdba.job_run(date_key,job_name,start_date,ctl_rows,load_data_row,end_date, flag_completed)
        values(pdate,pname,sysdate,10,0, null, 'N');
        end if;
        commit;
    end;
```

After that I run this below query to call PROCEDURE

```
BEGIN
EXECUTE CHECK_JOB('20200101','table2');
END;
```

I got this error:

> SQL Error [6550] [65000]: ORA-06550: line 2, column 9:
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CHECK_JOB" when expecting one of the following:
>
> := . ( @ % ; immediate
>   The symbol ":=" was substituted for "CHECK_JOB" to continue.
>     java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 2, column 9:
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CHECK_JOB" when expecting one of the following::= . ( @ % ; immediate
>   The symbol ":=" was substituted for "CHECK_JOB" to continue.

Comment: Not related to the error(s) you are getting, but is your update supposed to have the same filter conditions as the `select count(*)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the `EXECUTE`:

```
BEGIN
 CHECK_JOB('20200101','table2');
END;
```

Comment: or just `EXECUTE CHECK_JOB('20200101','table2');` (without begin ... end;)

Comment: BEGIN  CHECK_JOB('20200101','table2');END; -->Got this error SQL Error [6550] [65000]: ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PLS-00905: object MISDBA.CHECK_JOB is invalid
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
  java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PLS-00905: object MISDBA.CHECK_JOB is invalid
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: EXECUTE CHECK_JOB('20200101','table2'); --> Error SQL Error [900] [42000]: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
  java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Comment: @SNPalita - `EXECUTE` is a client shortcut so may only work in SQL\*Plus, SQL Developer and SQLcl - others may have copied it though. Whatever you are running this though clearly doesn't support it though, so stick to begin/end. Your procedure is invalid though, so query `user_errors` or `all_errors` to see why. (But looking at it i think you just need to remove the `declare` keyword?)

Comment: @AlexPoole - Thanks a lot, i will try another client program.

Comment: @SNPalita - that's not what I was suggesting; your current client can handle an anonymous block, it just doesn't know the `execute` shorthand. The PLS-00905 is because your procedure is invalid, that's nothing to do with which client you are using. Recompile your procedure without `declare` and see if that is successful, once the procedure is valid you will be able to run it as Aleksej showed, from your current client.

Comment: @AlexPoole - I have removed the declare and it's work!. Thanks a bunch.